# Number multiplied by itself does not give a square number

Tags: square-numbers

The answer to this is probably very simple but while working on a question I was surprised to discover than a number multiplied by itself does not give the same answer as the same number squared (in the case of negative numbers).

Examples:

$-1^2 = -1$

If I now multiply this number by itself $-1 * -1$ I get $1$

$-4^2 = -16$

$-4 * -4 = 16$

The same goes for all the other negative numbers I tried.

What changes when squaring a number and how do I understand what is going on?  When I multiply a positive number by itself I get a square number, why does this not work with negative numbers?

Comment: It's just operator precedence.  $-x^2$ does not mean $(-x)^2$, it means $-(x^2)$.

Comment: What you've done above is not squaring a number.  It is true (depending on how you interpret order of operations) that $-1^2=-1$.  But what you are actually asking about is $(-1)^2$ which is exactly $1$.  *By definition*, $x^2$ is the same thing as $x\cdot x$.

Comment: @NickPeterson So it's actually (-1)1^2

Comment: @Robert Israel thank you I understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the square of $-1$ is $$ (-1)^2 = (-1)\times (-1) = 1 \ne -1 .$$ You've mixed up operator precedence by putting $$ -(1)^2 = - (1) \times (1) = - 1 . $$

In general $-(x)^2$ is $- (x\cdot x)$, because exponentiation has a higher operator precedence than negation. You can read more about the order of operations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Comment: I see I understand now.  I'll accept your answer.  Thank you, it was as obvious as I expected